# how to stop reloading the data in custom cell?

Tags: objective-c

in my custom cell data will be reloading how can i stop that data?

here is my custom cell code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ContestTableViewCell *cell = [myContestTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *myNib;
        myNib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ContestTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell =[myNib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (selectedIndex==indexPath.row) {

    } else {

    }

    cell.fldExamTitleLbl.text = [fldExamTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.fldExamStartDateLbl.text = [fldExamStartArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.prizeMoney.text =[prizeMoneyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.firstReward.text = [firstRewardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.secondReward.text = [secondRewardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.thirdReward.text = [thirdRewardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

the screen will appears like this

Comment: Was your image meant to be outside of the code snippet? Also what is meant to be in the empty if statement? Are you missing out code?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing it correct. You should load the nib once and then register it in the table view for a reusable identifier. This is best done in `viewDidLoad` or some other constructor after the subviews are loaded:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCellNib" owner:self options:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCellNib" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCellIdentifier"];
```

The cell identifier may be anything you want then but use the same one when dequeuing cells.